# What is the meaning of "dishing it out" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

the headline is:

"Female soccer players are done taking abuse. let’s stop dishing it out."

a link to the matter is :

"https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/03/sports/soccer/women-soccer-league-abuse.html"

I read throught it but could not make a concordance with "let’s stop dishing it out" to

"Female soccer players are done taking abuse."

Answer (score 2):

The article is written by a man. 'Let's' is a contraction of 'let us'. 'Us' here refers to the author himself and all other men. The writer is saying 'Female soccer players will no longer tolerate abuse. Let us (men) stop giving it to them'.

To 'dish out' is literally to serve food onto plates before a meal, and figuratively to issue or dispense something in a casual or indiscriminate way.

When a bully behaves rudely or abusively to others, often for no obvious reason, but reacts angrily when they return the behaviour, people may say 'he/she can dish it out, but he/she can't take it'.